# Call C# dll from Python

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I am trying to call existing C# dll from Python.
I tried both Python for .NET and Iron Python.
I put dll (LogAccess.dll) just under the Python root.
In the case of Python for .NET, just under the Python27 directory.
In the case of IronPython, just under th IPy27.

```
import sys
import clr
clr.AddReference("LogAccess")
from LogAccess import LogAccess
```

at this point, error occurs.
This is the same situation in Python for .NET and IronPython.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled", line 4
    clr.AddReference('LogAccesss')
FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'LogAccesss'.
   \u5834\u6240 Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)

What is wrong ?
Is there any condition to make C# dll ?
Is there any rule where dll is placed ?
I wnat to know relationship among modulename, namespace and main program name/

Comment: Could you try `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath` in IronPython and an absolute path to `LogAccess.dll`? This also ensures that the containing folder is added to lookup paths. You could also have a look at the assembly being blocked and not loaded for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

First Check wether your single line

```
import clr
```

is not giving any error

if not then try putting you file inside Python27/Lib/Site-packages directory and try the same  .

Or else you can specify the path

```
import sys
sys.path.append("yourDllPath")
```

then try importing the way you are doing